# Connection is still not closing in connection pool after using session.close()

Tags: hibernate

[image][image]I'm using hibernate application and my web server is wildfly 17. I'm using session.close() method through out the application but active connection size in connection pool is increasing continuously. and after the max pool size connection close issue occurred. [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjq54.png)

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of pools is to keep objects that are expensive to create/initialize.
Since database connections take some time to establish your connection pool will keep them so other tasks will start faster.

When you call `session.close()` Hibernate returns the connection to the datasource. The datasource itself keeps the connection (without closing it).

Depending on the connection pool implementation (and settings) connection might or might not be closed after some time. Pools will typically run simple requests (such as `select 1 ...`) to keep the connections alive while they're sitting in the pool.

Comment: I'm using session.close() through out the application but my active connection is not being reduce after performing any operation from the UI side. My question is that if i'm using session.close() then why active connection count is not being reduce.

Comment: Because session.close() returns the connection to the pool and the pool does not close returned connections.